# Issue installing Opencv on Raspberry Pi 4 with gnu compiler/default C++ library

Tags: python, opencv, gcc, raspberry-pi

I have Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian (updated to latest release) and tried to get Opencv. I have Python 2.7, all the dependencies, etc. I am working in a virtual environment but have another version install on a non-virtual version and I got the same error.

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd ~/opencv-3.1.0/build
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.1.0/build $ make
[  2%] Built target libwebp
[  4%] Built target libjasper
[  7%] Built target IlmImf
[  7%] Built target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
[  7%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
[  8%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  8%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_RELEASE.gch
In file included from 
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:59,
             from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:62,
             from /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:53,
             from /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
             from /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:52,
             from /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/modules/core/precomp.hpp:49:
/usr/include/c++/8/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: 
No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_core.dir/build.make:64: modules/core/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_RELEASE.gch] 
Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2336: modules/core/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_core.dir/all] 
Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

cv is my virtual environment. The error occurs in a file in the default C++ directory that comes with the pi. The c++ standard library can't find the C standard library in the same folder. I've checked they are both there and both unedited. I am wondering how the gnu compiler only has access to part of the C++ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling precompiled headers:

```
-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF
```

Delete directory `build`.

Try this:

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd ~/opencv-3.1.0 
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.1.0 $ mkdir build && cd build
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.1.0/build $ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF  <here_your_options>...
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.1.0/build $
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.1.0/build $ make
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.1.0/build $ sudo make install
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is added on with -D to the cmake instruction? not too familiar with gnu. I tried that and got the following from the console. It can find my python version and I've gotten past this step before so does the cmake not let you create another makefile? The following was in the error log 'Determining if the include file linux/videodev.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Comment: I also tried to delete everything and start from scratch, this time putting your comment in the cmake file. It produced a Makefile, but now the error occurs even sooner when trying to make (0% instead of ~18%) and I tried to make the Makefile using a newer version of the Gnu compiler and it said it didn't recognize the format of the Makefile.

Comment: @Bibambop64 I improved the response.

Comment: I deleted old build folder, made a new empty one, ran cmake with my preferences, ran make, got the same error at the same place
'[  1%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_RELEASE.gch
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:62,
                 [repeats from this folder from that folder etc down to this]
/usr/include/c++/8/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
'

Comment: I have gnu 9.1, would it be worth it to try making with that? Raspbian only has 8.3 I believe. Also I wouldn't know how to write the syntax but know it's something along the lines of g++-9.1 -std=c++17  -Wall -pedantic CMakeFiles -o [directory its in?]